# solving the partial diffential ODE $ y^{s} (x)=y(x) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, fractional-part

how could i solve the differential equation with frational derivatives

$$ \frac{d^{s}}{dx^{s}}y(x) =y(x)$$

here 's' is a real number

my idea is to make the ansatz with the series $ y(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} $ and apply this series to the linear ODE.

but i have problems to get what cauchy initial conditions should i put in case of fractional derivatives..

Comment: Are you interested in power series solutions only?

Comment: Your problem has a complete solution in this [book](http://www.amazon.com/Fractional-differential-equations-derivatives-integrals/dp/3639715306).